# How to use environmental variable in explorer for quick folder access?

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I am a user of Windows 8.

I frequently create and save document files to a folder with long path. Therefore I tried to create a environment variable for that folder `MyFolder`, to get fast access.

However it does not seem to work: inside Notepad++ or other editor, when I open "save as" and enter `%MyFolder%`, it does not navigate to the desired folder.

Is there a way to achieve such functionality?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

```
SETX MyFolder <folder path>
```

Maybe logoff need, test at `cmd`:

```
cd %MyFolder%
```

Comment: No logoff required, but you do need to start a new command prompt to test with `cd %myfolder%`. Otherwise, just do start -> run -> %myfolder% immediately after running the setx command.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which asked how to access environment variables in Windows Explorer (not from the CLI).

Answer (score 0):

These folders are now called "KnownFolders" and replacing the former CSIDL. But I don't know if there are any windows tools to create them directly, you have to write your own or find a 3rd Party tool.

KnownFolders
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb776911(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

CSIDL
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/csidl?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if you explained the content from the links yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To somewhat further elaborate/clarify what STTR was saying...

Creating the environment variable from the cmd prompt will actually work 
May take a moment to process *(do not include any % in the command)*.

- SETX %VARIABLE% "Variable Destination Path"

After "success" appears, you can then use windows explorer's address bar to test your newly created variable.
(not sure why someone commented that STTR's answer was not an answer, as it clearly is an answer).

Comment: And who is James?

Comment: I meant STTR, edited and fixed